# ISQL Six Digits Limitation

Tags: isql

I wanna get rid of isql six digits limitation. How can i overcome this ?

" isql displays only six digits of float or real data after the decimal point, rounding off the remainder."

If WE get it from sql advantage we can see all digits after comma. But if we start it from batch file we can not see the rest after six digits.

You can see different result from the screenshot below

[Click Screenshot](http://www.sekerfx.com.tr/FX/taxt.jpg)

Any suggestion ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Are you referring to Informix' `isql` or Firebird's `isql`?

Comment: Please add some more information regarding your problem, what you tried and what you expect.

Comment: No sybase isql.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1570/html/ocspsunx/X33477.htm